# When does a function not have continuity where it's defined?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

I.e. a function such as $\tan \sqrt{\log x}$.

Comment: Your title and question ask two different things. Do you want to know the definition of continuity at a point where the function **is** defined (as in the title)? Or do you want to know the definition of continuity at a point where the function **is not** defined (as in your question)? You should rewrite the title and question to be consistent with each other.

Comment: Thanks. I clarified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most that can be said about this in general is that one should learn to apply the definition of continuity and the theorems of calculus regarding continuous functions.

Your specific example is a composition of three functions each of which is continuous at every point of its domain, namely $f \circ g \circ h(x)$ where $f(x) = \tan(x)$ is a continuous function with domain $x \in \mathbb R - \{(2k+1)\pi/2 \mid k \in \mathbb Z\}$; and $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is a continuous function with domain $x \in [0,\infty)$; and $h(x) = \log(x)$ is a continuous with domain $x \in (0,\infty)$. Continuity of all three of these functions is proved in advanced calculus; here's an outline.

Continuity of $\sqrt{x}$ is pretty easy exercise directly from the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of continuity.

Continuity of the logarithm function is probably best proved by using the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Continuity of $\tan(x)$ and other trig functions are perhaps best proved using theorems about infinite series expansions, although they can also be proved using a combination of the fundamental theorem of calculus and the inverse function theorem for continuity.

Another theorem of calculus says that a composition of continuous functions is continuous at all points where it is defined; perhaps this theorem gives the most direct answer to your question.

Putting this all together, $\tan \sqrt{\log(x)}$ is continuous at all points where it is defined.